# Alternative to using dd in windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, dd

In a build operation I am attempting to do on Windows (7, if it matters), I need to execute the command `dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=data.bin of=disk.flp` on object code from assembly (nasm with `-f bin`). Is there a way to do this **without** installing any programs? To reiterate, installation of third-party programs is *entirely impossible* on this workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something all you want is to append the data from data.bin file to the end of disk.flp file. If so, it should be easy with CreateFile - SetFilePointer (to the end of file) - WriteFile

Comment: I think _I'm_ missing something though... This is what is used to convert the assembled output into what **should** be a valid floppy image.

Comment: Are you building a boot loader? If so just write the data.bit to the first sector of the floppy by using CreateFile to open floppy and WriteFile to write to it

Comment: What language is this in/how do I do this? I use a Linux most of the time, so I'm unfamiliar with MSW methods...

Comment: Those are the names of Windows internal file manipulation functions. You can call them from pretty much any language, including assembly.

Comment: Here's a sample, including the detailed info on boot sector: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/files/article.php/c13809/Extract-Floppy-Disk-Geometry-from-the-Boot-Sector.htm

Comment: `HANDLE hFloppy = NULL;
hFloppy = CreateFile(
          "\\\\.\\A:",        // Floppy drive to open
          GENERIC_READ,       // Access mode
          FILE_SHARE_READ,    // Share Mode
          NULL,               // Security Descriptor
          OPEN_EXISTING,      // How to create
          0,                  // File attributes
          NULL);              // Handle to template` I just replace the `\\\\.\\A:` with `data.bin`? And where does `disk.flp` come in? To clarify, I'm creating a disk IMAGE, not burning the bootloader to a disk.

Answer (score 0):

dd is available for Windows.

Best up to date source that I've found is bundled with Git for Windows. With that installed the binary lives here **C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\dd.exe**